# Predicate logic of sorting algorithm

Tags: predicate-logic

I'm confusing with this question. How can we tranlate a sorting algorithm for a list of N numbers to predicate logic, especially for insertion sort? Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you attempted to figure this out on your own?

Comment: you may have to use many rules of inference like modus ponens.